# make several forms with single file inputs on change of a multiple file input using javascript

Tags: file, input

I want to make forms with single file inputs dynamically with the files selected using a multiple file input.

I have something like this:

```
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="selector" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        </form>
```

on $("#selector").change() I want to make forms like the following and associate internal inputs with selected files:

```
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input id="selector" type="file" name="file">
        </form>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, just encapsulate it in a div, then change the html content of this id, in other words:
HTML:

```
<div id='myForm' >
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="selector" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</form>
</div>
```

then you can do :

```
$('#selector').change(function(){$('#myForm').html('<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input id="selector" type="file" name="file </form>')});
```

Comment: no I think u miss-understood me. I want multiple selected files to be dispensed between several single input files so that I can submit them seprately

Comment: sorry for my missunderstanding, but if I got it correctly this time, you want to implement a functionality similar to jQuery File upload, you can check it from [here]:(http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), and if you just don't want to use that, I have to notify that multiple single file uploads are a lot less efficient than a single multi-upload form, that's why the main browsers added the multi-select functionality, anyway if you still want to do it this way, the only thing i can think of now, is to regiter the file, and append the form again in the same area.